# Declaring a non-static class as static

Tags: c#, static, static-methods, non-static

I have a static class called `A`:

```
public static class A
{
}
```

And another class called `B`, which is not static:

```
public class B
{
}
```

After that, I declared the non-static class `B` as static:

```
public class c
{
    // declare a non static class (B) as static
    public static B b = new B();
}
```

What is the difference between `A` (static class) and `b` (non-static class declared as a static class)?

Comment: One is static and the other isn't?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `static class` you can *only* declare static members (methods, fields, properties). In a non-static class, you can declare both static members and instance (non-static) members.

Also, you cannot derive a class from a static class, or instantate it, or use it as a type argument.

---

When you define a static member:

```
public static B b = new B();
```

...then you are saying that this field `b` of type `B` belongs only to the type you declared it in. Non-static fields belong to an instance of the type.

---

For example, if you have:

```
class MyClass
{
    public static string myStaticString = "";

    public string myInstanceString = "";
}
```

Then if you change the `myInstanceString`, its value will only change for that particular instance:

```
MyClass myInstance1 = new MyClass();
MyClass myInstance2 = new MyClass();
myInstance1.myInstanceString = "1";
myInstance2.myInstanceString = "2";
Console.WriteLine(myInstance1.myInstanceString);  // Prints: 1
Console.WriteLine(myInstance2.myInstanceString);  // Prints: 2
```

But if you change the `myStaticString`, its value will change for everyone that uses the type:

```
MyClass.myStaticString = "1";
MyClass.myStaticString = "2";
Console.WriteLine(MyClass.myStaticString);        // Prints: 2
```

And that is completely unrelated to whether `string` (or `B` in your example) was declared as `static`.

Comment: And, of course, you can't instantiate a static class (or rather, you can only have one instance of it).

Answer (score 0):

The difference is the difference between the **[static variable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691162%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)** and the **[static class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/79b3xss3%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)**. `b` is a static variable of non static type `B`, However `A` is a static class.